# How to share bandwidth equitably between 16 users on a pfsense multi-WAN router

Tags: pfsense, traffic-shaping

I have 16 users connected to my pfSense single-LAN, 3-WAN router.
The 3 WAN ports connect to ADSL lines giving about 4Mb/s down, 800kb/s up each.

I would like to prevent any one user hogging the available bandwidth, while at the same time allowing a user to saturate the link if they are the only one using it.

I guess I need traffic shaping. But search the web as I might, I can find no clue how to do this, unless I set up 16 separate incoming and outgoing queues (and set up more queues if we get a new user).

I did try using the traffic shaper wizard, but its output makes no sense to me at all. I just went through without separating out any specific traffic for high or low priority, and it produced this:

```
     Bandwidth   Priority   Service curve
WAN1         800 Kb/s
   qACK      20 %      6    - - 20%
   qDefault  10%       3
WAN2         800 Kb/s
   qACK      20 %      6    - - 20%
   qDefault  10%       3
WAN3         800 Kb/s
   qACK      20 %      6    - - 20%
   qDefault  10%       3
LAN
   qLink     10%       2
   qInternet 10752 Kb/s     - - 10752Kb
      qACK   20%       6    - - 20%
```

All this seems to achieve is to cut the available bandwidth to about 30% of what it was. Which, in view of the total of the % bandwidths for each queue, is perhaps not surprising!

Also, I can't find any firewall rules that directs traffic into these queues - does that mean none are needed if I don't have different queues for different types of traffic?

Are there any experts out there I could pay to show me how to set this up?

Comment: I recall a coworker of mine use snort and used a packet shaper to manage bandwidth based on MAC address.  If I find/recall the details, ill post it up.

Comment: Don't run the wizard and use the rules it creates as such. They are severely broken and will cripple your network. Even your LAN throughput will get crippled. HFSC is more complicated than that. The problem is larger than it seems. The shaper is meant to balance bandwidth between different queues (P2P, browsing, VoIP etc.) and have them all perform well, not multiple connections in the same queue. You have multiple users all using the same queue so one of them can still hog the bandwidth.

Comment: So I guess I need to set up 1 queue per user? I'm really surprised no-one has written any kind of guide for this!